# Validation annotations NOT working at all (Tried all suggested solutions)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use the `@Valid` and `@NotBlank` annotations in my spring boot project within IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-222.4345.14, built on October 5, 2022

I have added dependency like below in my project pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In my entity class i have added `@NotBlank` annotation as below

```
@NotBlank(message = "Please add the department name")
private String departmentName;
```

In my controller class i have added `@Valid` annotation as well

```
@PostMapping("/departments")
public Department saveDepartment(@Valid @RequestBody Department department)
{
    return departmentService.saveDepartment(department);
}
```

Even with all this i don't think the validation APIs are working.

My spring boot version is

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Ideally i should be getting validation error if i don't pass the department name in my POST request BUT i never get any error with blank department name where my annotations are present.

I have tried various suggested solutions like closing and restarting IntelliJ Idea, Rebuilt the project. Also, I have tried invalidating the cache. NOTHING IS WORKING !!! The dependencies also seem to be all GOOD.

What else I could try?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the scope `test` from the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency, you need this dependency during runtime as well.

Create a unit/integration-test that can test your validation. Run the test using a Maven command like `mvn clean test`. If this succeeds and the same test fails when executed within IntelliJ, you have an IDE issue.

Comment: Good suggestion but that didn't work. What worked is that IntelliJ IDEA update to IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-222.4459.24, built on November 22, 2022

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my IntelliJ IDEA Community to latest available version which is below and everything worked good after this

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-222.4459.24, built on November 22, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.5+7-b469.71 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1004M
Cores: 8

Kotlin: 222-1.7.10-release-334-IJ4459.24
```